# Play video using canvas

Tags: java, android

I am developing live video wallpaper application in android, which would take a video and set it as a live wallpaper. However, I can not use videoview as drawing is done only on canvas and I am not sure how to play a video using canvas.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the frames from video as byte array and display on canvas by converting this byte array as bitmap  and call the following method.

```
canvas.drawbitmap(yourbitmap,0,0,null);
```

More information can be had from the following link.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have already figured out that thing but the issue is how to convert the video of almost any format into frames and store them into byte array?